# Different PrepublishScript for different publish profiles

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, csproj, msbuild-task

I have an asp.net core web appication (Visual Studio 2017) and in the .csproj file there is a PrepublishScript Target that is being executed when (before) I publish the application to a location.

I have two different publish profiles, each one publishing the application to a different location and with different settings.

How can I have different PrepublishScript Targets for each publish profile (or at least have conditional execution in this target depending on the publish profile I am publishing)? I don't want to execute the same steps for all publish profiles.

Is there a way to set a variable from each publish profile, that can be read from msbuild and execute tasks conditionally depending on that value?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different options:

1. **Move the targets to the publish profile.**

Publish profiles are just MSBuild files and contain everything that a project file can. If the profiles are so different that you can't really share logic between profiles or managing conditions will get messy, adding the targets to the publish profiles is a good way to maintain profile-specific logic.

2. **Define properties in the publish profiles**

Since they are MSBuild files and already contain a `PropertyGroup` element, you can define any custom property inside this file and use it inside a target or as a condition on the target.

E.g. in the `my.pubxml` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishFooConfigFile>true</PublishFooConfigFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then this can be used in the main csproj file:

```
<Target Name="IncludeFooConfig" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish" Condition="'$(PublishFooConfigFile)' == 'true'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="config" RelativePath="%(Identity)" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

3. **Use the `PublishProfile` property as condition**

When you are building with e.g. `/p:PublishProfile=Foo`, you could also use `$(PublishProfile)` for MSBuild conditions, but this is a **bad practice** because it hard-codes a profile name that might not have to do anything with the actual logic and there are additional ways to specify a publish profile which would break this logic.

Comment: I will try the first approach. Moving the targets to the publish profile.